# 'Bad substitution' error in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I keep getting a 'bad substitution' error in my bash script at the point ${basename $option} where '$option' is input later in the script, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
function findByExtension {
strip=${basename $option}
extension="${strip##*.}"
```

}

I have also included '#!/bin/bash' at the start of the script.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend. It would have caught this (and many other errors) for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to perform command substitution there, not parameter substitution.

```
strip="$(basename "$option")"
```